# Умная выборка MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток.

Стоит следующая задача:

В **MySQL** присутствует табличка, она имеет такие колонки:

- chanse
- ElementID

**Пояснение:**

Колонка *chanse* может принимает шанс, от 1 до 100 (логично, собственно).

А колонка *ElementID* просто *ID* какого-либо элемента, ничего особенного.

**Задача:**
Нужно вынуть с базы рандомную запись, где, например, **ElementID = 1**, и при этом мы должны еще учесть шанс, то бишь если шанс стоит 100, то эту запись мы рандомно должны выбирать чаще, чем запись с шансом в 50 процентов.

Вот такая система ниппель. Спасибо за вашу помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала получаем сумму всех шансов

```
select sum(chance) as s from tab;
```

Потом в php получаем рандомное число в интервале от 0 до <сумма шансов>.
Тогда запрос:

```
set @c = 0;
select id, chance, @c:=@c+chance as cc 
from tab
having cc>=$rndvalue
order by cc 
limit 1;
```

вернет запись в соответствии со своими шансами. Надо только проверять, чтоб не было выхода за границы int...

**N.B.** Вычисление значений переменных в запросах происходит "лениво". Поэтому, модифицируя запрос каким-либо образом, можно получить неработающий запрос в виде:

- переменные не просчитались на момент их использования:

  ```
  select id, @c:=@c+chance as cc from tab where @c>$value
  ```
- переменные просчитались дважды, если использовать вложенный запрос:

  ```
  select * from (select id, @c:=@c+chance as cc from tab) q where cc>...
  ```
- переменные просчитались не в том порядке:

  ```
  select id, @c:=@c+chance as cc from tab
  having cc>FLOOR(rand()*(select sum(chance) from tab))
  ```

И другие побочные эффекты, объяснить которые бывает порой сложно. О них можно почитать тут: [Lazy evaluation](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/#toc_3) и в [доках](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)